# VBA how login with MSXML2.XMLHTTP

Tags: vba

I don't understand meaning of `.SetRequestHeader`

Here is a code for login on some website

```
Function webLogin()

   Dim Cookie As String

   Set oXHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

   oXHTTP.Open "POST", "http://someURL/login", False, "admin", "adminpw"
   oXHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
   oXHTTP.Send



   Cookie = oXHTTP.GetResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")


   oXHTTP.Open "POST", "http://someURL/ord?station:%7Cslot:/", False
   oXHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Cookie", Cookie
   oXHTTP.Send


   Debug.Print oXHTTP.ResponseText

End Function
```

This code is working but can't login.

I think it is because of the wrong use of `SetRequestHeader` and that the website has a submit button but this code does not click the button.

Comment: It's pretty much impossible to say what the problem is without knowing the actual URL and how they handle logins.

Comment: thanks your reply  url is ip like 192.168.0.200 and login code is thats all...

Comment: are you trying to log into an IOT device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can tell you the usual way a login would work with any website and any object that supports webrequests.

First start with a GET request to the login site and get all necessary data. From that GET request you will usually get at least a session cookie. Additionally you will get all the data you need to submit for the login post. So your first step should be to open the login page with google chrom/firefox whatever in developer mode and check out the whole login process.

It is not rare that websites uses stuff like CRSF-Token or other fields in the webpage with some kind of unique id. Sometimes it can be found in the header, sometimes it is a hidden field within the body that needs to be send in the POST request to login.

So if you found out, which cookies and what POST data is required. Your next step would be to send the actual POST request, including the cookies from the first GET request and filling ALL required POST data. This is at least username and password (the exact names can be found in developer mode in your browser).

From that POST request you will get most likely another cookie and a redirect to the start page where you logged in.
So you would need to use all those cookies for all further GET requests to the websites behind the login.

Comment: I'd like to be able to vote for this answer more than once... Thanks, @Mono!